# Plone 5 TinyMCE, Can't select a folder for uploading image

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-5.x

At Plone 5, I can't select a folder for uploading image.
How can I select another folder for uploading image?

[image]

Comment: Seems you are looking into the /ecphyw/files folder. Are you sure you have any other subfolder there?

Comment: Yes, I have `/ecphyw/files`. And I want to add an image into the folder. Actually, The image put on Plone root.

Comment: What you want to reach is not clear to me. If you alreay have the image in the Plone site root, just navigate to the site root and select it.
If you want to upload the image in /ecphyw/files, click of the "ecphyw" in the breadcrumbs of the widget, the select "files" and the button below.
This widget suffer or usability issues. See also https://community.plone.org/t/about-the-new-plone-5-related-items-widget/1462/7

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I  want to upload the image in `/ecphyw/files`. But I can't select `files` in `ecphyw`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I can't select". However we are off-topic there, this seems not a developer issues. Think about join the Plone community forum: http://community.plone.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistook this question. This problem was related my env.